# Record all conference legs in FreeSWITCH

Tags: session, record, channel, freeswitch, conference

I’m trying to record phone conferences, so that later on their audio can be reviewed.  The requirement is to record each leg in a seperate file.  After doing some googling, one way of doing it, is by using record_session and setting RECORD_STEREO to true.  That will result in caller and receiver audio streams being placed in separate channels.

I am using this code in the dialplan before the bridge app:

```
<action application="set" data="RECORD_STEREO=true"/>
<action application="record_session" data="$${base_dir}/recordings/${strftime(%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S)}_$1_${caller_id_number}.wav"/>
```

The problem is I could not split the channels to get the individual streams and I have all the streams in all the recorded files.

Any idea how I can fix this little issue.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't really need to use `RECORD_STEREO` – `RECORD_WRITE_ONLY` will do it.

```
<action application="set" data="RECORD_WRITE_ONLY=true"/>
<action application="record_session" data="/opt/freeswitch/recordings/archive/${strftime(%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S)}_${destination_number}_${caller_id_number}_write.wav"/>
```

That way you'll have a separate file for each person that enters the conference.